# Is there a way to monitor resources used by Extensions in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I am wondering if there are any tools built-in or available from a third party for profiling active Extensions in Visual Studio 2010? I am getting some slowdowns after I installed a few Extensions, but I am trying not to disable each Extension one-by-one while I wait to see if a slowdown continues to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Unless you're seeing a hang at a certain point where you could attach a debugger and see who is on the stack, you're probably best off just disabling a few and see if it gets better. Of course, check the extension reviews in the Gallery to see if there are any comments about a certain extension having issues.